# How to whitelist good bots in fail2ban

Tags: nginx, web-crawler, whitelist, fail2ban

We have a server running `nginx` and `wordpress`. Access logs have been disabled to reduce disk I/O and increase performance. I have enabled custom logs for multiple specific uri which logs `host` `date/time` `method` and `uri` into a specific files. For some uri like `/phpmyadmin` or `/xmlrpc.php` I am directly banning the IP the moment server receives a request. Now I want to white-list known search engines like `AOL.com` `Baidu` `Bingbot/MSN` `DuckDuckGo` `Googlebot` `Teoma` `Yahoo!` and `Yandex`. I know how to white-list an IP, but have no idea how to while-list a whole lot of spiders.

Comment: In your filter you can setup ignore regex, so if you are able to pass the FQDN rather than IP to your logs then you can set fail2ban to ignore something.aol.com and apply everything else as per normal filter.

Comment: thanks. SO how can I get the list of all FQDN used by these search engines.